# SQL Trigger after insert update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to update an entity in a table after a insert is done in another table. Here my current trigger which doesn't work.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateLastValues]  
ON [dbo].[MeasureValues] FOR INSERT   
AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MyValue AS nvarchar;
DECLARE @MyTimestamp AS datetimeoffset;
DECLARE @MyId AS nvarchar;

SELECT @MyValue = Value FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @MyTimestamp = Timestamp FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @MyId = MeasurePointId FROM INSERTED;

UPDATE [dbo].[MeasurePoints] SET  [dbo].[MeasurePoints].[LastValue] = @MyValue, [dbo].[MeasurePoints].[LastEdit] = @MyTimestamp WHERE [dbo].[MeasurePoints].[Id] = @MyId
END
```

Measure Values receive new values. The latest values should be saved in MeasurePoints LastValue Column.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an error message or a useful problem statement. Please tell us exactly what happens - e.g. do you get an error, or does it not produce the expected result? It might help to give us an example of the input data, and then what the desired outcome should be.

Comment: Your trigger has a major flaw here, it ***assumes*** that your table will only ever have 1 row inserted at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Trigger from `FOR INSERT` to `AFTER INSERT`.

Also, I have made some changes in the Code to remove the Unnecessary codes

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateLastValues]  
ON [dbo].[MeasureValues] AFTER INSERT   
AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE MP
    SET
        LastValue = INSERTED.[Value],
        LastEdit = INSERTED.[Timestamp]
    FROM [dbo].[MeasurePoints] MP
        INNER JOIN Inserted
            ON MP.id = Inserted.MeasurePointId

END
```

Comment: `FOR` and `AFTER` are the same in SQL Server, so changing `FOR` to `AFTER`  makes no difference (See FOR | AFTER in [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). Changing the trigger to a dataset approach though, now that makes a big difference. :)